# Label positioning in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I am using lualatex and I am having trouble positioning the labels of a grouplot at the bottom of the plots. Here is my code

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} 

\usepackage{fontspec}                    
\usepackage{polyglossia}                 

\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}                     
\usepackage{mathtools}                   
\usepackage{amscd}                       
\usepackage{amsxtra}                     
\usepackage{amsthm}                      
\usepackage{unicode-math}                

\usepackage{tikz}                                     
\usepackage{pgfplots}                    
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}                

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}          
\setmathfont[bold-style=ISO]{Cambria Math}     

% pgfplotsset style
\pgfplotsset{
    gaxisonly axis/.style={
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->}, 
    ticks=none,
    clip=false
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=4 by 1,
xlabels at=edge bottom,
vertical sep = 1.5cm},
gaxisonly axis,
height=4cm,
width=4cm]
\nextgroupplot[xlabel={Function 1}]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-0.5:0.5,samples=100, thick]{abs(x)};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel={Function 2}]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-0.5:0,samples=100, thick]{-x};
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=0:0.5,samples=100, thick]{x^(1/3)};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel={Function 3}]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-0.5:0.5,samples=100, thick]{sqrt(abs(x))};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel={Function 4}]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-0.5:0.5,samples=100, thick]{x/abs(x)*abs(x)^(1/3)};
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-0.5:0,samples=100, thick]{-abs(x)^(1/3)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some functions}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and here is the result

[image]

As you can see the text is above the x axis of the plots instead of the bottom. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This label positionning occurs because of `axis lines=middle` in the `gaxisonly axis` style. [According to the pgfplots doc](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), this parameter sets something like

```
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.left of origin)},anchor=south west}
```

Two way to avoid this:

- Use `axis lines*=middle`, which in your case will provide correct results
- Add something like `every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.south)}, anchor=north}` after setting the line style.

Comment: The second method worked perfectly, thank you.